# PDF to web page

Tags: html, pdf

I get a .pdf complete with images, fancy fonts, styles, gradients and what have you.  Basically it's handed off to me with the message, "Make me a web page that looks exactly like this."  I've tried a few pdf to html tools and they all look terrible.  I figure I've only got 2 options and i hate them both.

1. convert the pdf to one big image and use an imagemap to add the links.
2. the screen copy tool that comes with acrobat reader to chop the file up into it's parts (buttons, logos, etc).

She uses Quarks to make this pdf.  I've never used it, but I hear it is very popular.  Are these really my only two options?  Someone tell me I'm wrong, please.

Comment: I think the program you are talking about is QuarkXPress, not Quarks.

Comment: I have no idea...I've saw the QuarkXPress and wondered the same thing.  She always calls it Quarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab what text you can out of the PDF and clean it up. Pull the PDF into Photoshop and slice out the graphical elements you want to use. Rebuild the page using the images and put your text in HTML format.

Make a slice of the gradients and use them as background images with repeat.

Try to explain to your client why the fancy font is unsuitable for this medium.

Edit:

If it's just going to be a screen shot, you might as well just put the PDF up in the first place. At least people can zoom in.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use one big image map.  The more content you can convert from image to text, the better (more efficient) your HTML page will be.

Chop up the PDF into parts.  Make the logos, etc. images, make text plain text, and make buttons button controls.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly like what Diodeus said except-

-
Find the fancy font and check to see how much it will cost to license or buy it. Build two bills and send them to your client, one with the fancy font and one with a standard font. Then see if she wants the fancy font. It will show that you take your job serious and may get you less strict project conditions.

Comment: Haha; evil! This would be necessary only if the font were to be used in an image, or if the font were served with the HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not:

Adobes Online pdf to html [service](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/access_onlinetools.html)

or

[pdftohtml](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: i tried both of these services.  they were great for getting the text out, but not so much for the graphics.  pdftohtml made one big graphic of the pdf minus the text and then absolute positioned the text in html.  the other made the graphics completly unusable.

Comment: Ok-there are some html export tools avaiable for Quark, maybe some of them will do the trick?